# Installing Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5

I'm currently using Entity Framework at my job, but I've recently try to get it on my personal computer but I still didn't find a way to get it. Sure, I've searched on google but not really find any exe and not any thread that explain that.

Thanks to help me out!

** EDIT **

I've now access to System.Data.Entity. But I've not the "Entity Data Model" ... how can I get this tools !!

Comment: what development environment do you have at home?? As far as I know, the .NET 3.5 SP1 and thus the Entity Framework can only be installed in Visual Studio 2008, so if you have VS2005 at home, you're out of luck

Comment: No I've got a VS.net 2008 Team Edition Liscence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running programs using the Entity Framework requires only the .NET Framework 3.5 with SP1, as stated by Astrofaes.

Writing EF programs requires Visual Studio 2008 (I also use a Team edition, should work with all editions) with SP1. From the comments above I believe you lack the SP1 (this SP actually adds 3.5 libraries support to VS).

(this would have been a comment to the previous answer had I already the right to comment, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit obvious but have you installed .NET Framework 3.5 service pack 1?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en

Comment: Yea sure, I've instaled .NET Framework 3.5 and also get the service pack 1. I've readed that EF its include in SP1 but it's not ... at least, I don't see it at the same place then my computer's job if its instaled.

Comment: If I fallow this link : http://thoughtscroll.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/steps-to-install-entity-framework-for-visual-studio-2008-windows-xp/, two of the links arn't workin'. And if I try to run the "EFToolsSetupX86.exe", it says that it can't be install because I need to instal one of the   "beta" applications listed.

Comment: You can check if the framework installed properly by looking in your registry. Browse to this key:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\

It's value should be 3.5.30729.01 if it's correctly installed.

Comment: It's exactly this update... Do I need a specific "version" ... I mean i've a "Team system"

Comment: Ohh, well. I just saw that i've got the "System.Data.Entity". So I think it's correctly installed. But, at my job i've got an XML Model creating tools which it's not supplied framework 3.5 SP1 ?

Comment: He's the erro message when I try to install "EFToolsSetupX86.exe" = "ADO.NET Entity Framework TOols Preview can only be installed if at least one of te fallowing Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Beta 2 Products is installed : Visual Basic 2008 Beta 2 Express Edition, Visual C# 2008 Beta 2 Express Edition ..." and more "Beta" version.

Comment: Do not try and install the EF separately. That predates 3.5 SP1, and you don't need it. Just install 3.5 SP 1 (1Along with the corresponding VS 2008) by itself.

Comment: Well after comming back to work, a collegue tell me that I also have to install a VS.net SP1 which I totally forget. Exactly as u said Craig. Thanks.